# I want to paint a shelf in White , and a mask in it like image attatched. Should i use oil based or acrilic?

Tags: paint, wood

[image]
I want to paint a shelf in White , What should i use?

[image: a]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a home improvement project, not traditional arts and crafts.

Comment: Use white paint.

Comment: @AllisonC, I'm having trouble figuring out where we draw the line around A&C.  Lots of craft projects involve making something from wood and applying a finish, which is often paint.  In this question, the wooden thing is long and flat and has household utility, but the question is about the painting.  Painting a house wouldn't be considered arts & crafts.  Painting a small wooden object probably would.  Something this size seems within the crafting realm.  The requirements for the paint here (it needs to stand up to abrasion and chipping), are common for crafting items of utility.  (cont'd)

Comment: If someone was hand-making, say, an Adirondack chair or a coffee table and wanted to paint that, would that be considered crafting within the site scope?  Is refinishing wooden trunks or small furniture items considered crafting within the site scope?  I'm hoping for some input before I vote on this one.

Comment: I'm with rebusB on this. An alternative, more detailed answer: use white paint suitable for wood. @CIMend: what makes this plank so special you need to ask this here?

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree. That it's about home improvement is an assumption (but I would like more details from CIMend to see if it is maybe justified), and it's nevertheless still not about the *usage* of an object, but about the *customization* of that object - albeit at its most basic level.

Comment: @ClMend if this answers your question, I'm not sure how good a fit the question is for the site, but a shelf should typically either be painted with non-water-based  paint, or if water-based paint is used, overcoated with a non-water-based finish.  Water-based paint tends to absorb humidity and soften, so items stationary on a shelf will stick to it.

Comment: I want to put it prettier painting a mask in it like image attatched

Comment: @ClMend, it isn't clear what specific problem is giving you trouble on this project.  What would a good answer address?

Comment: Yes, please write down what exactly you want to do, and how you think you will do it, and what step(s) you need help with. Write down as much as you can think of, in clear words.

Comment: @fixer1234 - those are good questions for meta. But nothing is stopping you from answering it as you see fit. OP asked a basic question with no details... same would apply if one asked "I have a coffee table and I want to paint it green, what paint should I use?" Its too open ended.

Comment: @ClMend, also, please clarify what the end result will be.  After painting, will the shelf be used as a shelf to hold stuff (only prettier than it is now), or are you creating an art panel on wood, and the shelf happens to be the right size to use as the medium?

Comment: You know what people, just because this seems less artistic than other projects, redoing an old shelf to make it like new it can still be considered a crafts project for someone who hasn't done this kind of thing. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I agree . Vote to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the masking in of the mask design for now and answering original question.

The choice of paint is up to you. As fixer1234 noted you are better off using oil based enamel paint as it gives a harder more permanent finish but latex will do if you want to avoid solvents and messy cleanup.

You would want to sand and prime the board first. Match the primer to the paint you plan to use. Sand after priming, maybe use two coats if the wood is extra thirsty or the old finish still shows through. Same goes for your finish coats.

To add a design, make a stencil or hand paint it after applying the base coat. Be sure if you are using a different color that it is the same type of paint (latex or oil enamel).  Then apply a clear coat to protect it, also of the same type of paint.

I am not going to go into paint brands or how to prep and clean brushes etc... that you can find out for yourself with a little basic research.

Comment: first i used the primer